# Dates range containing with infinite intervals

Tags: sql, oracle, algorithm, plsql, oracle11g

I have a function in `Oracle` that checks if the first date contains the second one. There is no problem with it, because `[a, b]` contains `[x, y]` if `x => a and y <= b and x <= y`. Works fine for defined `start/end date 1` and `start/end date 2`. But now I want to modify it. If any of given 'starting' dates is `NULL` it should be treated as `+-infinite`.

It's a code:

```
  FUNCTION CONTAINS(p_START_DATE_1 DATE, p_END_DATE_1 DATE,
   p_START_DATE_2 DATE, p_END_DATE_2 DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS

   lv_RESULT VARCHAR2(1);
  BEGIN 
       lv_RESULT := 'N';      

       IF (/* milions of conditions here */) THEN
         lv_RESULT := 'Y';
       END IF;

       RETURN lv_RESULT;
  END CONTAINS;
```

**For instance:** Suppose that `p_START_DATE_1` is `NULL`. In this case that code:

```
SELECT MY_PACKAGE_SQL.CONTAINS(
       NULL,
       TO_DATE('01/12/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
       TO_DATE('01/02/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'),
       TO_DATE('01/05/2012', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))
FROM DUAL;
```

... should return `Y`, because first date range is `(-infinite, 01/12/2014]` and it contains  `[01/02/2012, 01/05/2012]`.

Now my problem... I know I can use additional `"IFs"` to check `NULLs`. But I wonder if it's any other solution to make it faster in `Oracle's PL\SQL` language? It's like `do it in smarter way challenge` in my team `:)`

Comment: Can you use `p_start_date_1 := coalesce(p_start_date_1,p_start_date_2,1)` and `p_start_date_2 := coalesce(p_start_date_2,p_start_date_1,1)` etc? (1 may need to be an actual low value date). And similar for the upper bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If only dates *can't be null* you can put it like that:

```
  IF ((p_END_DATE_1 >= p_START_DATE_2) AND
      (p_START_DATE_1 <= p_END_DATE_2)) THEN 
    lv_RESULT := 'Y';
  END IF;
```

when *having nulls* you can declare that, say

```
  -Infinity == 1 Jan 1
  +Infinity == 31 Dec 3999
```

So with a help of `Coalesce` or `Nvl` function you can implement

```
  IF (coalesce(p_END_DATE_1, TO_DATE('31.12.3999', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) >=
      coalesce(p_END_DATE_2, TO_DATE('31.12.3999', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) AND
      coalesce(p_START_DATE_1, TO_DATE('1.1.1', 'dd.mm.yyyy')) <= 
      coalesce(p_START_DATE_2, TO_DATE('1.1.1', 'dd.mm.yyyy'))) THEN 
    lv_RESULT := 'Y';
  END IF;
```